# Relationship between compactly supported homology and homology with orientation sheaf

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be noncompact and non-orientable manifold of dimension d. Is it true that $H_{c}^{d-i}(M;Q)$ and $H^{i}(M;Q^{w})$ are isomorphic, where $Q^{w}$ is orientation sheaf and $Q$ is a field of rational number.

Comment: Do you mean "orientation sheaf" or "orientable sheaf"?

Comment: I mean orientation sheaf.

Comment: Then I would say this is pretty much the standard form of Poincare duality for not necessarily oriented, not necessarily compact manifolds.